# How to read Parent Attribute value of an XML through Java if its Child Attribute value matches

Tags: java

Here My XML file and the size of my XML file is more than 100 MB .............

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <products inbound.code.version="" schema.version="" xslt.version="0" hierarchy.type="provisioner" hierarchy.remap="emea" hierarchy.language="en" hierarchy.country="eu" hierarchy.translation="en" hierarchy.depth="product" remap="product" depth="0">
    <product.type name="myprod" translation="myprod" change="modified" oid="84609819" oid.2="84609819" common.oid="3709945" remap="category" depth="1">
    <category name="myprod Adapters" translation="myprod Adapters" change="modified" oid="84609824" oid.2="84609824" common.oid="3710111" remap="category" depth="2">
    <sub.category name="myprod Ethernet Adapters" translation="myprod Ethernet Adapters" change="modified" oid="81995406" oid.2="81995406" common.oid="1844132" remap="category" depth="3">
    <big.series name="Nova myprod Ethernet Adapters" translation="Nova myprod Ethernet Adapters" change="modified" oid="81996409" oid.2="81996409" common.oid="496741" remap="category" depth="4">
    <small.series name="Nova myprod Dual NC370i Multifunction Network Adapter" translation="Nova myprod Dual NC370i Multifunction Network Adapter" change="modified" oid="81997928" oid.2="81997928" common.oid="496742" remap="category" depth="5">
    <model name="Nova BL20p G3 Dual NC370i Multifunction Network Adapter" translation="Nova BL20p G3 Dual NC370i Multifunction Network Adapter" change="modified" oid="82020916" oid.2="82020916" common.oid="496746" remap="category" depth="6">
    <product name="Nova BL20p G3 Dual NC370i Multifunction Network Adapter" translation="Nova BL20p G3 Dual NC370i Multifunction Network Adapter" number="product1" change="modified" oid="64857725" oid.2="64857725" common.oid="496743" remap="product" depth="7"/>
    </model>
    <model name="Nova BL20p G3 Dual NC370i Multifunction Network Adapter" translation="Nova BL20p G3 Dual NC370i Multifunction Network Adapter" change="modified" oid="82020916" oid.2="82020916" common.oid="496746" remap="category" depth="6">
    <product name="Nova BL20p G3 Dual NC370i Multifunction Network Adapter" translation="Nova BL20p G3 Dual NC370i Multifunction Network Adapter" number="product2" change="modified" oid="64857725" oid.2="64857725" common.oid="496743" remap="product" depth="7"/>
    </model>
         </small.series>
        </big.series>
       </sub.category>
      </category>
     </product.type>
    </Nova.products>
```

I have to enter one product number as a search argument through Java, if the product matches at number="product number entered through Java
in depth="7" then i have to get the common.oid attribute value from depth="6" .

Answer (score 0):

try to parse this xml-doc with the sax parser (recommended for read-only);

override the startElement(...)-method:

- if the start-element is an candidate, then store it in an variable;
- if the start-element matches your needs, you can refer to the parent;

override the endElement(..)-method

- if (the end-element is an candidate (analoge to startElement) then set the candidate null.

this snippet might help:

```
private Object candidate; //you must define your own kind of candidate!
public void findIt(){ //stupid name, you can do better
    try {
        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

        DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {

            @Override
            public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

                if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase(candidateTagName) ){
                     candidate = new Object();
                     //populate the candidate with required infos
                     //use  attributes.getValue(attributeName).trim();
                     //this is your parent on level n
                }   

                if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase(childTagName) ){
                     //now you found your child at level n+1
                     //and you can refer to parent at level n:
                     candidate.getSomething();
                     //or do something
                     //or even return something (requires method return value change)
                }   
            }

            @Override
            public void endElement(String arg0, String arg1, String arg2) throws SAXException {
                super.endElement(arg0, arg1, arg2);

                if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase(candidateTagName) ){
                    candidate = null;
                }

             }
        }
    };

    saxParser.parse(xmlFile, handler);

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

well - your candidate Object must be defined, you can do this better than i can!
and define your tags